# Every rake task seems to run some sort of test, how can I stop it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake, minitest

Ever since I created this Rails 3.2.3 project to use MiniTest, I have been receiving these messages at the rake command line:

```
Loaded Suite test/factories,test/helpers,test,test/models,test/requests

Started at 2012-05-22 10:04:01 -0400 w/ seed 45382.

Finished in 0.000229 seconds.

0 tests, 0 passed, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips, 0 assertions
```

Which is strange in itself, since I have several tests defined and they run fine. The messages above are superfluous, and they are confusing. How can I get rid of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is loading the autorun file in test/unit. Once that file gets loaded, an exit handler gets setup that will print out the number of tests that have been run at the end of the process.

To fix it you need to identify which gem is causing the autorun file to be loaded, and to stop requiring it automatically in your Gemfile.

In my case, the "culprit" was nutrasuite. To fix it I edited the Gemfile so that nutrasuite was added like this:

```
gem "nutrasuite", :require => false
```

You'll need to make sure that whichever library is causing it is required in your test_helper.rb file, but that's really how it should be setup anyway.

You can identify what's causing the problem via a process of trial and error. Hope that helps...

Comment: Hopefully to help avoid some of the trial and error, shoulda was the culprit for me and the fix was just as Graham said: gem "shoulda", require => false in Gemfile and require 'shoulda' in test/test_helper.rb. This issue helped me isolate it: https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-context/pull/4.

Answer (score 0):

You can also move it to its own group.

```
group :test do
  gem 'nutrasuite'
end
```

In my case, it was because I had minitest loading from the gemfile.